# The computer does not wake up from sleep after a RAM upgrade

Tags: 10.04, suspend-resume, acer

I have been using this build (and sleeping it) for months without a problem.
Yesterday I upped the RAM from the pre-installed 4gb across 2 sticks to 8gb across 2 sticks....

Machine boots fine and is fast and stable in the OS....

When I now sleep the machine it will go down fine, but on wake it just dies. A reboot is required.

---

From the logs:
/var/log/pm-suspend.log

---

Previous to RAM upgrade:
(EXAMPLE of sequence)

```
/etc/pm/sleep.d/action_wpa suspend suspend:success.
Fri Apr 1 16:29:00 EST 2011: performing suspend
Fri Apr 1 18:50:18 EST 2011: Awake.
Fri Apr 1 18:50:18 EST 2011: Running hooks for resume
```

After to RAM upgrade:

```
/etc/pm/sleep.d/action_wpa suspend suspend:success.
Sat Apr 16 22:16:12 EST 2011: performing suspend
Initial commandline parameters:
Sat Apr 16 22:45:09 EST 2011: Running hooks for suspend.
```

There is no 'Awake' reference – this is now replaced with the commandline parameters??

Any ideas?

Comment: same thing happened to me

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this works, but I'd try resizing the swap partition. Maybe it's to small to copy all data from ram into it?

Comment: AFAIK the swap partition is only written to when you use hibernate, sleep just leeches power to keep the RAM state alive while the kernel is unloaded and the HDD is powered down. I may be wrong? It feels to me that this is a hardware issue. Although the RAM is working fine in the OS, it doesn't appear to get enough power under sleep conditions to keep the state alive. I have been using hibernate now and it is fine.......